# Intentionally removing volumes in override docker-compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For production deployment, I don't want shared volumes. So, I have an override file but this does not remove the volumes.

Is there a way to remove shared volumes in an override file? I'd like to avoid having an override just for development, because that seems clunky to use.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
# other services defined here
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    # other configuration
    volumes:
      - .:${APP_DIR}
```

And my `docker-compose.prod.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    volumes: []
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When merging a list entry in `docker-compose`, it adds new maps but doesn't remove existing volume mappings.

You can implement this by either making dev have the override file, or up to version 2.1 you can [extend a common docker file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services) rather than applying overrides which lets to devs point to a single file.

This could be your docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
# other services defined here
services:
  web:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.prod.yml
      service: web
    build:
      context: .
    restart: no
    volumes:
      - .:${APP_DIR}
```

And your docker-compose.prod.yml would contain all the common configuration and prod settings:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    # other configuration
    restart: always
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves the problem. Isn't volumes still defined when both compose files were merged? Also, what do you mean with _You can implement this by either making dev have the override file_?

Comment: @Johnny I'm suggesting the compose files be reversed, instead of extending prod from the dev definition, extend dev from the prod definition.

Comment: Thats how I did it after all. Still feels dirty some how buts it's the best I could find.

Answer (score 31):

I'm assuming you want to use `docker-compose up` to start the development version, and have a second config file to extend it for production.

If you want to make sure to override volumes completely, use a third config file, `docker-compose.override.yml`. Put all your volume definitions for development in there.

`docker-compose up` extends the base config with this file *by default*. But when you do something like `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f production.yml`, the `docker-compose.override.yml` file won't be loaded, and you'll get only the volumes from the production file.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Spent a while trying to figure out how to make the overrides work. IMO this is better than having prod be the default as it does not force you to specify multiple files when running dev commands.