# Disabling volume in docker pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline that runs inside a docker. One of the steps in the pipeline is writing to a file. I want to run this pipeline multiple times and every time it runs, it creates container on the host. The problem is, that Jenkins automatically creates volume to the docker container which makes the pipeline fail because both of the containrs trying to write to the same file at the same time, as they share the same volume. How can i make the docker not creating a volume and only create the file inside the container so it won't interfere one with the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intentionally removing volumes in override docker-compose files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020286/intentionally-removing-volumes-in-override-docker-compose-files)

Comment: Not really. I'm not deploying a container woth docker compose, i am running Jenkins pipeline insode a container